# SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: insert or update on table "states" violates foreign key constraint "states_country_id_fkey"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to Insert data with Sequelize Sync function. but i am get this error. problem is some times data got enter successfully and sometime doesn't

error

```
config/sequelize.js:295
SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: insert or update on table "states" violates foreign key 
constraint "states_country_id_fkey"
at Query.formatError 
(d:\projects\petrolpump\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:315:16)
at Query.run (d:\projects\petrolpump\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:87:18)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {name: 
'SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError', parent: error: insert or update on table "states" viol…ign key 
constraint "states_country_id_fkey"
…, original: error: insert or update on table "states" vio…gn key constraint "states_country_id_fkey"
…, sql: 'INSERT INTO "states" ("id","name","country_id"… 
untry_id","is_active","createdAt","updatedAt";', parameters: Array(5), …}
```

this is query

```
sync function initial() {
try {
var country = await db.country.findOne({ where: { name: 'India' } });
if (!country) {
  db.country.create({
    name: "U.S.",
    is_active: "true"
  });
}

var state = await db.state.findOne({ where: { name: 'Gujarat' } });
if (!state) {
await  db.state.create({
    name: "California",
    country_id: "1",
    is_active: "true"
  });
 }
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
  }
}

db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
  console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
  initial();
});
```

This Is the assoctiastion

```
db.state.hasMany(db.city, {
  foreignKey: 'state_id'
});

db.country.hasMany(db.state, {
  foreignKey: 'country_id',
});
```

I have tried using reference in model file but got sane error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the error. idon't know it's error because of version but when i have installed old version which works for me it's 5.21.3

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error while building an API using NodeJS and Sequelize. Here is how I was able to solve the problem.

ERROR:
SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: insert or update on table "states" violates foreign key
constraint "states_country_id_fkey"

From the error above, it shows that the state table requires the country_id as its foreignKey. Meaning, you won't be able to create a state if the stated country_id is absent in the country table.

SOLUTION:
I would recommend seeding the "country" table first to ensure the specified country_id referenced in the "state" table is present.

Then try inserting data into the state table. That should solve the problem.